# Movie/series where arrestee causes truck to crash into police car by making the truck invisible to the police officers

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm looking for a movie or tv-series episode that I saw years ago, probably between 2002 and 2012, where this scenario happened:

- A man (might have been a bald man) is transported by two police officers in the back of their police car (possibly to be taken from/to jail)
- The police car is parked on the side of a road, or at a gas station or at the police station/jail
- A big semi-trailer truck is approaching their location from afar, on the road where the car is parked next to. The truck might have been blue, just as the sky in the background.
- The man has some scifi/magic powers and speaks a phrase (like a magic spell) that sounded something like 'blue as the sky', which makes the truck invisible to the police officers (the truck does not actually disappear, it only becomes invisible specifically to the police officers)
- The police car then proceeds to drive onto the road (because they think there is no traffic because of the magic) and then the truck crashes into the car
- 50% sure that the the damage to the car allows the man to escape

It was live-action, not animated, and English language. It was probably a high-budget production, it felt like a 90s or later production.

Comment: Possibly [*The Highwayman*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Highwayman_(TV_series)), a short lived series with hi tech trucks - one of which could turn invisible? That was late 80s though.

Comment: @DanielRoseman No unfortunately not: it was definitely the 'magic' of the man in the back of the police car that made the police officers not see this one specific truck

Comment: The phrase was "Cerulean is a gentle breeze", the truck had the word "Cerulean" printed on the side.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe this is the X-Files episode (although from 1996 and the guy wasn't bald) - [The Pusher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pusher_(The_X-Files))

> In this episode, Mulder and Scully’s assistance is requested for a case involving a man, who goes by the pseudonym "Pusher", seemingly capable of bending people to his will. The suspect uses his mysterious abilities to manipulate Mulder into a dangerous end game.

... and the scene I believe you're referring to:

> Robert Patrick Modell (Robert Wisden) walks through a supermarket, buying a large supply of energy drinks. Before he can leave, Modell is surrounded and arrested by FBI agents led by Frank Burst (Vic Polizos). While being escorted away in a police car, he repeatedly talks about the color cerulean blue. Modell's talking seemingly causes the driver to not see an approaching semi-trailer truck of that color, causing a collision. Modell escapes after the driver unlocks his handcuffs before dying.

> Burst, the only surviving agent of the crash, tells Fox Mulder (David Duchovny) and Dana Scully (Gillian Anderson) about his pursuit of Modell—nicknamed "Pusher"—who has committed a series of contract killings over the past two years, making the acts appear to be suicide.

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks so much! I just found the specific clip also, thanks! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=piy_HqOcVys&ab_channel=ArtemBaranov

Comment: @dennis_vok on a side note - if that was an episode you enjoyed... there's effectively a sequel - [Kitsunegari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsunegari)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!